# MongoDB issues with Grails Scaffolding (do not occur in MySQL)

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I tried using MongoDB 2.0.6 to replace MySQL 5.5.25 for a test Grails 2.1 App and am encountering some strange problems.

Issues when using MongoDB but not MySQL:

1. When using Scaffolding, I cannot get the fields to order by using static constraints
2. When I specify inList as a constraint, I get a drop-down when using a MySQL backend, but a field when using a MongoDB backend.
3. No * (asterisk) on fields where `blank=false` constraint specified.

**Domain Class**:

```
package study

class Student {

    String login
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String gender
    Boolean active

    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static constraints = {
        login()
        firstName(blank: false)
        lastName(blank: false)
        gender(inList: ['M', 'F'])
        active()
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
package study

class StudentController {

    def scaffold = true
}
```

**DataSource.groovy** (MySQL stuff commented out):

```
grails {
  mongo {
    host = "dev-linux"
    port = 27017
    username = "study"
    password= "********"
    databaseName = "study"
  }
}

//dataSource {
//    pooled = true
//    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
//    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
//    username = "study"
//    password = "********"
//    dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
//    url = "jdbc:mysql://dev-linux:3306/study"
//
//}
//hibernate {
//    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
//    cache.use_query_cache = true
//    cache.provider_class = "net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider"
//}
```

**BuildConfig.groovy** (plugins section shown was all I changed to put MongoDB in place of MySQL, the remainder of this file is the default created by Grails)

```
plugins {
      // build ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
      // compile ":mysql-connectorj:5.1.12"

      compile ":mongodb:1.0.0.GA"
      build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

}
```

The only changes I made to put in MongoDB and take out MySQL is the changes to the **DataSource.groovy** and **BuildConfig.groovy** shown above.

Is there any configuration item that I am missing?

I did see someone mention on this [Nabble forum post](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/2-0-1-order-of-fields-for-scaffolding-is-broken-td4445221.html) that the field ordering may be an issue with MongoDB.

However, this post did not have any details.

Also, I did not understand why or how the back end Database engine could impact how the view is rendered when using scaffolding.  Specifically, the ordering on a page and drop-down vs textfield.

I would have thought that would come from the Domain Class's field types and constraints.

Has anyone come across this odd behavior when using Grails+Scaffolding with MongoDB before?  Does anyone know of a fix or have any insight?

Thank you very much in advance, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaffolding with MongoDB works, the problem is if you just install mongodb plugin, grails will see ambiguous domain mappings and errors like these pop up. You need to either:

- Remove hibernate plugin like this:

  ```
  grails uninstall-plugin hibernate
  ```

  Also remove these lines from BuildConfig.groovy:

  ```
  runtime ":database-migration:1.1"
  runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
  ```
- Explicitly tell a given domain is persisted by Mongo by adding this line to it:

  ```
  static mapWith="mongo"
  ```

Comment: Thanks, Raphael.  Regarding your first point, I use IntelliJ and I am pretty sure that the Hibernate plugin is removed when I commented that dependency out of BuildConfig.groovy.  I believe that IntelliJ runs `grails uninstall-plugin` when you comment something out of BuildConfig.groovy.  However, I will go back and double-check in the .grails directory that the Hibernate plug-in is indeed gone.  I definitely did get rid of those 2 lines from BuildConfig.groovy that you mentioned.  I did not know about the `static mapWith="mongo"`, thank you for that information, I will try that.

Comment: Did you also comment out the migration plugin? It appears that it depends on hibernate so it might be transiently reinstalling it. 

 - https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-database-migration/blob/master/application.properties

Comment: Yes, I did remove the migration plugin.  I believe that got added by default when creating app, but I definitely removed it.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Raphael,

Thanks very much for your recommendations.  I upvoted your answer for being insightful, but I am still seeing the problems after trying the following:

1. Ran `grails uninstall-plugin hibernate` just to be sure.  Got message `| Warning No plugin [hibernate] installed, cannot uninstall` (which is what I would expect).
2. Verified that BuildConfig.groovy did not have database-migration, hibernate plugins. 
3. Added `static mapWith = "mongo"` to the Student domain class to explicitly specify it is persisted by MongoDB.

Comment: Try to download and run this sample app https://github.com/xymor/grails-mongo-sample and compare with your own or share your code so I can help you debug it.

Comment: I went to github and downloaded the sample app from your link and will give that a try.  Thanks.  I also edited original post so that it has all of my code.