# Grails MongoDB Plugin Unreleased versions: 1.0.1 OR 1.1.0.GA

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin

I am working on running down [MongoDB issues with Grails Scaffolding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012306/mongodb-issues-with-grails-scaffolding-do-not-occur-in-mysql).

I wanted to try more current versions to see if perhaps the issues I encountered have been resolved in later versions.

From the [Grails.org MongoDB Plugin Page](http://grails.org/plugin/mongodb), I see the current release is 1.0.0.GA.

This is what I am using:

```
plugins {
      compile ":mongodb:1.0.0.GA"
      build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
}
```

However, when I go to the [JIRA page for Grails MongoDB Plugin](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPMONGODB), I see 2 unreleased versions:

- 1.0.1
- 1.1.0.GA

Does anyone know where I could get these versions of the Grails MongoDB Plugin?  I don't mind pulling down a nightly build and building, just couldn't find where to get them.

I tried to find them on [GitHub Grails-Plugin](https://github.com/grails-plugins), but did not see it.  I could not find a way to download from the JIRA page.

Finally (as a last-ditch effort), I tried modifying plugins in `BuildConfig.groovy`, to reference 1.0.1 and 1.1.0.GA which did not work (probably since these versions are unreleased).

```
plugins {
      compile ":mongodb:1.1.0.GA"
      build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

}
```

Gave me the error:

```
| Loading Grails 2.1.0
| Configuring classpath
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.grails.plugins:mongodb:1.1.0.GA
```

Thank you very much, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugin's page on grails.org did actually reference [grails-data-mapping plugin group github page](https://github.com/SpringSource/grails-data-mapping). There is a tag 1.0.1-RELEASE there among others, but not 1.1, which is probably master.

Maybe you can build it from source and install from a local file, with [grails install-plugin](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-plugin.html).

Comment: Great, thanks Victor.  I'm getting those versions now from gethub.

Comment: hi, I found the 1.0.9.RELEASE on github. Which repo should I use to resolve this version?

Comment: That very repo - just make note it's not a branch, but a tag.